# Why does &14 in a = &14 only live one statement?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I don't understand why this works:

```
let mut i = &14;
```

and this doesn't:

```
let mut i;
i = &14;
```

Why doesn't `&14` get automatically the lifetime of `i` in this case? When is it useful to have "something = some new thing with lifetime of only one statement"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `let` has a special case that a plain `=` doesn't have (yet), where references assigned directly to the binding live for the closest enclosing block (approximately, the value is destroyed at the next `}`), rather than just the closest enclosing statement as they usually do (approximately, the value is destroyed at the next `;`). This explains the current error message:

```
<anon>:3:10: 3:12 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
<anon>:3     i = &14;
                  ^~
<anon>:2:14: 4:2 note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 2:13...
<anon>:2     let mut i;
<anon>:3     i = &14;
<anon>:4 }
<anon>:3:5: 3:13 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the statement at 3:4
<anon>:3     i = &14;
             ^~~~~~~~
<anon>:3:5: 3:13 help: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
<anon>:3     i = &14;
             ^~~~~~~~
```

That said, this also interacts with the new destructor changes, where the precise ordering of declaration of data is important to ensure safety of references. The `&14` expression currently means `let tmp = 14; &tmp`, so making that desugaring gives

```
fn main() {
    let mut i;
    let tmp = 14;
    i = &tmp;
}
```

which fails to compile with

```
<anon>:4:10: 4:13 error: `tmp` does not live long enough
<anon>:4     i = &tmp;
                  ^~~
<anon>:2:14: 5:2 note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 2:13...
<anon>:2     let mut i;
<anon>:3     let tmp = 14;
<anon>:4     i = &tmp;
<anon>:5 }
<anon>:3:17: 5:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 1 at 3:16
<anon>:3     let tmp = 14;
<anon>:4     i = &tmp;
<anon>:5 }
```

[The RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0769-sound-generic-drop.md) contains a lot of detail, but, in summary, to ensure safety for generic destructors, any data with references must point to something that strictly outlives itself, where "outlives" is considered at the statement level. In this case, `tmp` was declared after `i`, so it is illegal for `i` to contain a pointer to it.

There are some changes that may cause this code to compile, incidentally. `14` is constant data, so it can be placed in static memory, meaning `&14` could be a `&'static i32` instead of just a `&'short_stack_lifetime i32`. Both versions of the code would then be valid. This is [RFC issue #827](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/827).

Answer (score 2):

This is an edge case between the way that `let` acts and expressions act. Basically, `let` is a special case here.

In the first example, Rust understands that you're taking a reference to a stack-allocated `i32`.

In the second, you're introducing a binding, but then trying to use an assignment expression to update the binding. Because it's just a regular expression, things that it creates go out of scope at the end of the expression, and so, `14` here has the lifetime of just the expression, rather than the stack frame.